# Custom mail spool in symfony 1.4

Tags: email, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Can anyone give me a rough idea or link to instructions on how to create custom symfony swift mailer spool? I currently have the basic Doctrine spool which sends messages and deletes queue item.

I would like to do following:

1. Have a field with status (Sent, Unsent, Failed, Email does not exist, etc)
2. Update status field instead of deleting queue item on send

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never done such functionality myself, but it seems like you can create your own spool class:

```
<?php
    class Swift_MySpool extends Swift_DoctrineSpool {}
```

> Have a field with status (Sent, Unsent, Failed, Email does not exist, etc)

The `Swift_DoctrineSpool` class supports an option called `model`, where you can pass a name of class to store your mail at. So, just creating your custom model will take effect.

> Update status field instead of deleting queue item on send

Override `queueMessage()` and `flushQueue()` methods in your class and refer to [Swift_DoctrineSpool at symfony API](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/Swift_DoctrineSpool).

Hope this will help.